# curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to - Error in calling webservices

Tags: php, linux, curl

I am unable to call web-services that are deployed on another server

When I test the service using `curl` from command line

```
curl https://my_app_domain.com/testing_url
```

I get this error:

```
 curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to my_app_domain.com:443
```

That server has 2 apps deployed there, they both talk to each other and it's working all fine, issue is when I call services from another server (another app).

Comment: Do you have ssl certificate?

Comment: yes, we have that

Comment: May be the ssl is self signed or there is an error with domain names?

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the SSL version with your Curl option

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```